# JS reduce repeated code

Tags: javascript, reusability, code-readability

In my JavaScript file, I'm writting a piece of code several times:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   myFunction("this is a message");
}, 500);

setTimeout(function() {
   myFunction("this is another message");
}, 500);

setTimeout(function() {
   myFunction("this is another message again");
}, 500);
...
```

So, I want to avoid rewrite the setTimeout all the time.

Is there another way to compact the code and make a better and readable one?

Thanks!

**EDIT: My goal is not to launch "myFunction" sequentially. My goal is that when I call myFunction, it always delays 500ms to being executed.**

Comment: There is nothing wrong with calling the same function multiple times.

Comment: `setTimeout(function() {
    const messages = ["this is a message", "this is another message", "this is another message again"];
    
    messages.forEach(m => myFunction(m));
}, 500);

`

Comment: you could encapsulate with a simple function, something like: `function delay(m){ setTimeout(function() {
   myFunction(m);
}, 500)}`

Comment: Edited (in bold), sorry by the inconveniences :(

Comment: @Ommadawn Updated answer. Check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function to wrap the code you're duplicating, and let it take a message as input.

```
function delayMessage(msg) {
    return setTimeout(() => {
        myFunction(msg);
    }, 500);
}
```

It will return the timeout id in case you need to cancel it with `cancelTimeout`.  Then you can reduce your code to the following:

```
delayMessage("this is a message");
delayMessage("this is another message");
delayMessage("this is another message again");
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** If you want incremental delay, you just need to put the loop outside of `setTimeout` and make a IIFE:

```
var msgs = ["this is a message", "this is another message", "this is another message again"];
for (var i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++)
  (function (idx) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      myFunction(msgs[i]);
    }, 500 * i);
  })(i);
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
var msgs = ["this is a message", "this is another message", "this is another message again"];
for (var i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++)
  (function(idx) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      myFunction(msgs[idx]);
    }, (500 * i));
  })(i);

function myFunction(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}
```

Anyway the above code executes the function in 500th millisecond. Combine the three:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   myFunction("this is a message");
   myFunction("this is another message");
   myFunction("this is another message again");
   // ...
}, 500);
```

There's no difference between the above code and this. But you can make use of loops and arrays if you wanna make the code look good:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   var msgs = ["this is a message", "this is another message", "this is another message again"];
   msgs.forEach(function (msg) {
       myFunction(msg);
   });
}, 500);
```

Comment: Also there is no need for keeping messages/parameters to myFunction inside setTimeout, same scope as setTimeout will do just fine

Comment: @przemo_li Sorry, didn't understand that part. How can this be well written?

Comment: Edited (in bold), sorry by the inconveniences :(

Comment: @Ommadawn Simple fix. Updating.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
array = ["this is a message","this is another message","this is another 
message again"];

for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
         myFunction(array[i]);
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Edited (in bold), sorry by the inconveniences :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be calling the same function with the same delay every time, but the message is the only thing that changes. You could just do this:

```
const callMyFunctionWithDelay = message => setTimeout(() => myFunction(message), 500);

callMyFunctionWithDelay("this is called after half a second");
callMyFunctionWithDelay("this is another message");
```

If you want something more flexible and want to change the function, message and delay you can do this

```
const callWithDelay = (fn, message, delay) => setTimeout(fn.bind(null, message), delay);

callWithDelay(myFunction, "this is called after half a second", 500);
callWithDelay(myFunction, "this is gets called after 1 sec", 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
function myTimeout(msg, delay = 500) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    myFunction(msg);
  }, delay);
}

function myFunction(msg){ 
  console.log(msg)
  // or do something else ..
}
```

so now you can call `myTimeout('message')` and it will be delayed 500. 
Or you can call `myTimeout('message', delay)` where delay is an integer with the delay you want (in case you dont always want 500).

PS. i am not sure if this is what you asked but i hope it helps!